# Node number X (RESHAPE) failed to prepare. Tensor resize with tflite v2.2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

Here is a simple code to reproduce the error:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"

import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D, Flatten, Dense
import tensorflow as tf

model_path = 'test.h5'

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(8,(5,), input_shape=(100,1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.save(model_path)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile=False)
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)

tflite_model = converter.convert()

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)

interpreter.resize_tensor_input(interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['index'], (2,100,1))
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(interpreter.get_output_details()[0]['index'], (2,1))

interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-ad8e2eea467f> in <module>
     27 interpreter.resize_tensor_input(interpreter.get_output_details()[0]['index'], (2,1))
     28 
---> 29 interpreter.allocate_tensors()

<>/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py in allocate_tensors(self)
    240   def allocate_tensors(self):
    241     self._ensure_safe()
--> 242     return self._interpreter.AllocateTensors()
    243 
    244   def _safe_to_run(self):

<>/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter_wrapper/tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.py in AllocateTensors(self)
    108 
    109     def AllocateTensors(self):
--> 110         return _tensorflow_wrap_interpreter_wrapper.InterpreterWrapper_AllocateTensors(self)
    111 
    112     def Invoke(self):

RuntimeError: tensorflow/lite/kernels/reshape.cc:66 num_input_elements != num_output_elements (1536 != 768)Node number 3 (RESHAPE) failed to prepare.
```

It seems like the issue comes from the reshape function in the flatten layer. I've been able to execute this kind of resize with tensorflow 1.5 but not with the 2.2 version.

Here are the infos of the reshape layer:

```
 {'name': 'sequential_1/flatten_1/Reshape',
  'index': 8,
  'shape': array([  1, 768], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([  1, 768], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
```

I thought that maybe I should resize this layer too so I added:

`interpreter.resize_tensor_input(8, (2,768))`

but I got the exact same error.

`RuntimeError: tensorflow/lite/kernels/reshape.cc:66 num_input_elements != num_output_elements (1536 != 768)Node number 3 (RESHAPE) failed to prepare.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've come up with a workaround which reshape the model before converting to tflite by reshaping the keras model and then converting it to a concrete function and use from_concrete_function instead of from_keras_model.

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="-1"

import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D, Flatten, Dense
import tensorflow as tf

model_path = 'test.h5'

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(8,(5,), input_shape=(100,1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.save(model_path)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, compile=False)

batch_size = 2
input_shape = model.inputs[0].shape.as_list()
input_shape[0] = batch_size
func = tf.function(model).get_concrete_function(
    tf.TensorSpec(input_shape, model.inputs[0].dtype))
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([func])

tflite_model = converter.convert()

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_model)

interpreter.allocate_tensors()
```

Answer (score 1):

resize_tensor_input changes the batch size to 2, which seems to be triggering this issue.

TFL has pretty good support for batch size = 1 (the most majority cases) but larger batch size support is occasionally buggy. In some places this batch size param might get ignored. Could you try with batch size = 1 and see if it works?

When resize_tensor_input is called, TFL will use Prepare method to recalculate the input/output shape for all nodes in the computation graph. Any changes to the intermediate layers will be overwritten so `interpreter.resize_tensor_input(8, (2,768))` didn't help.

Comment: This issue only occurs when batch_size > 1

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to shape mismatches between the generator item data shape and the expected input shape you want to convert your model to.  I got this issue solved by making sure the batch sizes are aligned between `input_shape` and the generator item size.
Example: if the generator item shape is (50, 255, 255), declare the input shape as such